# Spring batch skip policy

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have 3 items
Chunk size =3
Item a : Failed case,as it has error
Item b : successful insert
Item c : Failed case,as it has error

When writer is inserting data as
All three items are not inserted successfully ,so Job is failed

Later on I implemented skip policy because of which my job is getting successful as  it is skipping failed and moving to next item to process

But first time it failed all three transaction …and then second time it works perfectly file
Is this nature of spring batch processing that even though skip policy is applied it will fail all records and then work fine

Code :

```
@Bean
 public Step step(WriterListener writerListener) {
  return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").<TransactionDetail, Tbl>chunk(chunk)
    .reader(reader).processor(processor)
    .writer(writer(datasource)).faultTolerant().skipPolicy(skipPolicy()).listener(writerListener).build();
 }
 @Bean
 public JobSkipPolicy skipPolicy()
 {
  return new JobSkipPolicy();
 }
```

I tried skip policy it is giving correct output as i desired
But when i debug
I internally saw for first time it is still going in onWriteError() method of writer listerner
Instead it should not go to onWriteError method for failed items only for rest it should go to onwrite() method of writer listener

Comment: Explaining my understanding here, In write listener interface, `onWrite` is called before the transaction is committed, so all the list of items (all chunks) will be passed to it. You can say if it will be failure when the transaction is committed. So when the any error occurs during write of chunk `onWriteError` is called and receives the whole list of items in chunk(all failed and committed). If you want only those items which are skipped, use `SkipListener`.

Comment: What I am seeing thrugh debugging is : beforeWrite is called before writing ,afterWrite will be called for all committee and successfully written items and onWriteError will be called for all failed and committed transaction .And if we are working with chunk size =3 then if 2 nd item failed and first and thired item failed then on running it will pass 1 st item to onWrite and second and third to onWriteError…but when i implemented fault tolerance thenit passed Ist and third item to onWrite and second item to onEriteError.Is my understanding correct?